# Local web application accepts numbers with comma and published does not

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

If I debug my local Webapplication it works. The input there is a decimal number with comma like "10,5". When I publish the webapplication to azure, the application don't accept numbers with comma anymore. 
When I enter on the publish application numbers with an dot like "10.5" it works but I get in the model "105". Has anyone a idea why?

Local:

[image: How it should works]

Published:

[image: How it not works]

Model:

```
public class MeasuredDataViewModel
{
    .....
    public List<MeasuredData> MeasuredData { get; set; }
    .....
}

public class MeasuredData
{
    public int MeasuredDataId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DataCategory")]
    public int DataCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
    public virtual DataCategory DataCategory { get; set; }

    public double Value { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OperatingData")]
    public int OperatingDataId { get; set; }

    public bool ManualIsChecked { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore(ApplyToOverrides = true)]
    public virtual OperatingData OperatingData { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Graph> Graphs { get; set; }

    public MeasuredData()
    {
        Value = 0.0;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" style="max-width:580px;">
                    <div class="col-xs-6" style="overflow-y:scroll; overflow-x:auto; height:650px; max-width:300px; display:block;">
                        @for (int i = 0; i < measuredData.Count; i++)
                        {
                            var me = measuredData[i];
                            var index = 0;

                            if (me.DataCategory.NumberId != 11.02 && me.DataCategory.NumberId != 20.02 && me.DataCategory.NumberId != 20.03)
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < Model.MeasuredData.Count; j++)
                                {
                                    if (Model.MeasuredData[j].Equals(me))
                                    {
                                        index = j;
                                    }
                                }

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MeasuredData[index].MeasuredDataId)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MeasuredData[index].DataCategoryId)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MeasuredData[index].OperatingDataId)

                                        <text>@me.DataCategory.Tag @me.DataCategory.NumberId</text>
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MeasuredData[index].Value, new { @class = "form-control",
                                                         @id = @me.DataCategory.NumberId + "-box", @style = "max-width:250px;"})
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br />
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
```

Comment: In Azure, default locale (culture) is `en-US`. Can you try by changing the locale to a value matching your local computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer you published to uses a different `CultureInfo` as the default (from the looks of it, I'd say `en-US` while you expect `de-DE`).

You need to set your CultureInfo. Do not rely on the default installed on the system. I don't know what you want to set it to, maybe the client's or maybe a specific one?

[Further reading on how to do it](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/306162/how-to-set-current-culture-programmatically-in-an-asp-net-application)